# swift - xcode - NavigationBarItem - change image to text

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have made a new ViewController with a NavigationController in front. Now i get this presentation in the navigationBar. This is any image from the view controller before. I did not set this image there. How can i change this to text  in xcode ?

[image]

In the storyboard i see this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Use Below code in `ViewDidLoad` to achieve that

```
        let imageBack = UIImage(named: "ic_back")!
        let btnLeftMenu = UIButton(type: .system)
        btnLeftMenu.bounds = CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: imageBack.size.width, height: imageBack.size.height)
        btnLeftMenu.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
//        btnLeftMenu.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.onBtnBackTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        btnLeftMenu.setImage(imageBack, for: UIControl.State())
        btnLeftMenu.setTitle("Cancel", for: .normal)
        let leftButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btnLeftMenu)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton
```

**ic_back** is a image name for back arrow image

Comment: THX, there is no way to do this in xcode with the attribute inspector or others?